# Iphone : Custom MKAnnotationView Callouts

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkmapview, mkannotation

I just spent the last hour looking through stackoverflow and Google for examples on doing custom callouts.  So not the actual pin that you click but the bit that appears above it.

What I want is to be able to put my own view above it.  So JAKERI example does custom views but does not place them near the pin (so if anyone knows how to place a view above the pin that would work), Asynchrony Solutions blog example extends the bubble I believe and seems like a overkills

So, is there a simple way to place your own view about the map pin on click?  I need to create quite a complete view with 5 lines, 3 images and a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading [this](http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/). I've used it before and it did the trick for me.

Comment: Sorry dude, I do mention that example in my post saying that I thought it was an overkill (Asynchrony Solutions)

Comment: Well - it took me 10 minutes to implement it and it really works as it should. Hope you'll find a better solution to it. Don't forget to share it if you do.

Comment: To be fair to you, I now started looking at this, sorry I down the answer, I cant change it :(  I might post my solution though

Comment: +1 for greater justice!1 Here is a more elaborated example: https://github.com/GiK/gik-animated-callout The callout is a UITableView. See a sample in HotelDetailViewController. You can run it on the iPhone if you set the target to iPhone and decrease the size.

Comment: I am really struggling to implement this in to my project, if I click on more than twice I have to click on the map to get the window backup, very wierd